# Google sign in (iOS) Authenticate with a backend server Invalid issuer error

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, google-signin

Hi im having **Invalid issuer erro**r when I validate the token id in server using google php API. Token is retrieved from iOS google sign in passed in http post request to the server.

PHP Code on verifying token

```
$client->verifyIdToken($token)
```

Error Return but with user credentials

```
Invalid issuer, https:\/\/accounts.google.com != accounts.google.com: {\"iss\":\"https:\/\/accounts.google.com\",\"at_hash\":\"ZYZ\",\"aud\":\"apps.googleusercontent.com\",\"sub\":\"XYZ\",\"email_verified\":true,\"azp\":\"XYZ\",\"email\":\"ZYP\",\"iat\":1449542280,\"exp\":1449545880}
```

I follow this instructions from google dev

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/backend-auth

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/aaa_idtoken

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok found out the problem. For people who might have problems like this in the future don't use the version stated in the google php api document which is `1.0.*@beta`. Use `1.1.*` or Higher

```
"require": {
  "google/apiclient": "1.1.*"
}
```

Found out in git repo that this issue was fix after version `1.0`

Comment: This is not specific to IOS, it applies to any client trying to validate an access token.